# mounting linux partition after installing windows

Tags: filesystem, mount

I installed windows 7 and my grub is gone. I'm trying to follow: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows
but I can't mount my ubuntu partion.

```
sudo fdisk -l

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              13        4863    38958080    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3            4864       14594    78157825    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           14220       14594     2999296   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Gparted shows my Extended partition as empty/unallocated space (???).
How can I mount it?

```
 sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sda3 /media/ubuntu

    mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda3,
           missing codepage or helper program, or other error
           In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
           dmesg | tail  or so
```

Comment: There isn't a Linux partition here. It seems you have overwritten it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've borked your system, `Ubuntu` was presumably installed in `/dev/sda1`, but you've overwritten it with Windows.

`sda3` is an Extended partition. In the past, it's thought that 4 partitions were more than enough, which turned out to be false. So they invented the Extended partition. A disk can contain 3 Primary partitions, and 1 Extended partition. The Extended partition itself cannot be used directly, it contains other partitions. In your case, it's the swap partition, `sda5`.

Answer (score 0):

An extended partition just contains partition definitions.  It's basically a placeholder for extra partitions beyond the initial four. In your case, the extended partition only holds a swap partition.  So it looks like Windows overwrote the partition Ubuntu was on.

From here, you could install a new copy of Ubuntu.  That's always the safest: Windows first, Ubuntu second.  And it looks like there's plenty room left for a new partition.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps installing Wubi would be the best course of action for you, Wubi installs like any other Windows program and can be easily removed the same way.

http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/windows-installer